# Trying to do a simple problem with command-line arguments, pointers have me stumped

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse the characters for each command line argument.

This is the only code inside my main method:

```
 for(int z = 1; z < argc; z++) //Loop through every argument
    {
        string arg = argv[z]; //Grab the argument
        string rebuildString; //Create a string to build the result
        for(int i = arg.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) //Loop through characters backwards 
        {
            char c = arg[i];
            rebuildString += c; 
        }

        char *rebuildChars; //So since argv is an array of pointers, I create a pointer here.
        *rebuildChars = rebuildString.c_str(); //Assign the value of the pointer
        argv[z] = rebuildChars; //Assign the current argument to the new value.
    }

    for(int x = 1; x < argc; x++)
    {
        cout << argv[x];
    }
```

Something is going wrong with my pointers and I am getting some incompatible type errors. Can anyone point out what's going wrong?

Comment: What do the error messages tell you - they are usually quite descriptive

Comment: What is `rebuildChars`? What is `*rebuildChars`? What does `rebuildString.c_str()` return?

Comment: Even more problematic, what happens with variables that go out of scope? For example a variable that is defined inside a loop, what happens when that loop iterates? What happens with pointers to data that the variable contain? You might want to study more about scoping and (more importantly) life-time of variables and objects.

Comment: All in all, it seems you could need [a good book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read.

Comment: `arg.size()-1` does evil things if the string is blank (subtraction from 0 in `unsigned` arithmetic). That's not the immediate issue here though; that's a *dangling pointer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that jumped out at me was that you assigning a pointer to a dereferenced `char*`.

```
    char *rebuildChars; //This is fine.
    *rebuildChars = rebuildString.c_str(); //ERROR! .c_str returns a char * !
    argv[z] = rebuildChars;
```

note the declaration of string.c_str() is `const char* c_str() const noexcept;` (C++11)

Instead try

```
    char *rebuildChars; //This is fine.
    rebuildChars = rebuildString.c_str(); //Here we assign a char * to a char *
    argv[z] = rebuildChars;
```

See [THIS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_string_c_str.htm) reference on TutorialsPoint.

Comment: Note that this doesn't solve the life-time problem. Or that the (invalid) pointers in `argv` could very well be exactly equal once the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `rebuildString` goes out of scope, it is destroyed, and the pointer previously returned by `rebuildString.c_str()` becomes dangling (pointing at freed storage).  So when you later try to print with it, you get undefined behavior.